# Is a font record index in BIFF8 zero-based?

Tags: c++, excel, fonts, openoffice-calc

I am programmatically reading and writing an Excel worksheet, using the source code from https://www.codeproject.com/articles/13852/basicexcel-a-class-to-read-and-write-to-microsoft, which in turn is based on the documentation of the Excel file format from http://sc.openoffice.org/excelfileformat.pdf.

The Excel file format supported by the source code is Binary Interchange File Format version 8 (BIFF8).

One of the records in an Excel file is an Extended Format (XF) record.  The first two bytes of the XF record is an index to a FONT record.  That is all the documentation has to say about it.

[image: Documentation of XF index to FONT]

My question:  Is that a zero-based index or a 1-based index?

The following is a use case that confused me and lead me to ponder this question.

## Use case: bold cell

I created a simple Excel worksheet:  one cell containing text that is bold.

[image: Simple worksheet with one bold cell]

I programmatically read that Excel worksheet and dump all the data to a human readable format, using new dump() methods I added to the source code.  I find that:

- My cell is associated with a LABELSST record:  `<LabelSST rowIdx=0 colIdx=0 xfRecIdx=62 sstRecIdx=0 />`
- That LABELSST record refers to an XF record with an index of:  62
- If that is a zero-based index, the XF record at index 62 is:  `<XF fontRecIdx=20 formatRecIdx=0 protect=0x1 align=0x20 rot=0 text=0 usedAttribs=0x8 borderLines=0 color1=0x2000000 color2=0x20c0 />`
- That XF record refers to a FONT record with an index of:  20
- If that is a zero-based index, the FONT record at index 20 is:  `<Font height=220 options=0 colorIdx=9 weight=400 escType=0 uline=0 family=2 charSet=0 name="Calibri" />`
- That FONT record has a weight of 400.

That font weight of 400 is **not** what I expected.  If my cell content is bold, then the font weight should be 700, as per the documentation.

[image: Documentation of FONT weight]

However, if the XF record refers to a FONT record with a 1-based index, then FONT record at 1-based index 20 is:  `<Font height=220 options=1 colorIdx=8 weight=700 escType=0 uline=0 family=2 charSet=0 name="Calibri" />`

And that FONT record does indeed have a weight of 700 to indicate bold.

This is confusing.  I do not know if the index to FONT record in the XF record is supposed to be zero-based or 1-based.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think I found the answer to my own question elsewhere in the http://sc.openoffice.org/excelfileformat.pdf documentation.

> The font with index 4 is omitted in all BIFF versions. This means the first four fonts have zero-based indexes, and the fifth font and all following fonts are referenced with one-based indexes.

If that is true, then the data I observed makes more  sense.